DOM objects are not draggable with jsPlumb Community Edition (6.2.10)
I am using jsPlumb Community Edition 6.2.10 with the following code:
<script src="~/lib/jsplumb/v6/js/jsplumb.browser-ui.umd.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

<div id="panel" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative; width: 25%; ">
    <div id="mybox" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: abolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    jsPlumb.ready(() => {

        // Intialize jsPlumb
        const instance = jsPlumb.newInstance({
            container: document.getElementById('panel')
        });

        // Check if box declared in html is draggable: Answer is NO!
        const mybox = document.getElementById('mybox');
        console.log('Is the box draggable?', mybox.draggable); 

        // Create a new box
        const leftPanel = document.getElementById('panel');
        const box = document.createElement('div');
        box.classList.add('box');
        box.style.position = 'absolute'; 
        box.style.top = `200px`;
        box.style.left = `20px`;
        leftPanel.appendChild(box);

        // Check if the added box is draggable: Answer is NO!
        console.log('Is the box draggable?', box.draggable);
    });
</script>

<style>
.box {
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>

Neither of the two boxes is draggable: in the console, I get the answer: "Is the box draggable? false" and when I try to drag one will not work. According to documentation: https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/6.x/lib/dragging in jsPlumb 5.x/6.x, all elements are draggable by default - there is no need to call the draggable function like in previous versions.

Calling jsPlumb instance.manage(box) method on the box fixed the problem.
